# Div does not auto scroll to show new messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a chatroom using socket.io. The chat works fine however, my message div does not auto scroll to show new messages. The user has to manually scroll. Let me further explain.

I added this code to my project:

```
$('.chatbutton').click(function(){
$display = $('#box');
$display.animate({ scrollTop: $display[0].scrollHeight }, 'fast');
});
```

Which means that when the user clicks the `chatbutton` and sends a new message, the div will automatically scroll down to that new message. This works, however the problem arrives when I open a second browser window and open up a second chatroom. What happens is that while the second chatroom is scrolled to its most recent message, as I type in my first chatroom, I have to repeatedly scroll in the second to see incoming new messages.

So essentially the problem is that new messages arrive, but other users cannot see them without manually scrolling their chatroom. Even if their chat is showing the most recent message, they have to continuously scroll to see new messages as they come in.

I had my friends and I test out the chatroom and we repeatedly had to manually scroll to see new messages. So it is an issue. How can I adjust my code above to fix this issue?

Let me mention that the code above allows the user to scroll up and view chat history while new messages come in, and I would like to keep that feature. However, when that user scrolls back down to the most recent message in their chat, I then would like the chatroom to auto scroll as new messages come in. (Basically the way Stackoverflow chatrooms function.)

I've tried using interval which solved my problem. However it created more problems for me because it prevents a user from scrolling up.

```
      window.setInterval(function() {
      var elem = document.getElementById('box');
      elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
    });
```

So again is there any way to adjust either code above to fix the issue?

**This is my chatroom html:** The first div is the chatroom. The second is where the messages accumulate. I then created a form that has two inputs which are to type a message and send.

```
<div id=box class="chatroom">
    <div class="chat" id="chat"></div>
</div>
<form id="messageForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input required="required" placeholder="Enter your message here" class="chat-message" id="message"/>
    <input class="chatbutton" type="submit" value="Send"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Let me know if there is any more code you guys would like me to add. Also excuse me if this seems like a duplicate but I've exhausted all my sources. So if it is please point me in the right direction. And if its not please guide me through to a solution.

I have explained everything precisely because I really would like help on this.

Thank you in advance.

-JJ

**Update** This is my script for socket.io

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var socket = io.connect();
        var $messageForm = $('#messageForm');
        var $message = $('#message');
        var $chat = $('#chat');


        $messageForm.submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', $message.val());
            $message.val('');

        });

        socket.on('new message', function(data){
            $chat.append('<div style="background-color:#fff;><strong style="color:#000">'+data.user+'</strong>: '+data.msg+'</div>');

         $chat.animate({ scrollTop: $chat[0].scrollHeight }, 'fast');

        });

    });
</script>
```

I placed the scroll function like suggested in my append chat however now nothing happens at all. And by nothing I mean before whenever I send a new message the div would auto scroll to that new message like i stated in my second paragraph above. But adding the scroll function to my chat.append caused nothing to happen at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### My answer

It likely you put your scroll script in the wrong event, so it'll run before the chat truly appeared in the div

`$display.animate({ scrollTop: $display[0].scrollHeight }, 'fast');`

Try to put that in the last line of your function which is used to load the new chats, after the new chats is appended to div. Not in $('.chatbutton').click event.

### about setInterval

you miss the second parameter:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
      var elem = document.getElementById('box');
      elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
});
```

should be: (when you want to call the function every 1 second)

```
window.setInterval(function() {
      var elem = document.getElementById('box');
      elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
},1000);
```

Comment: Didn't completely solve my problem but it did about 50%

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Express and trying to auto-scroll a  thats increasing in size as a result of additional messages being sent via socket.io broadcast/emit events, this solution should work for you.

`<script type ="text/javascript">`
`>>$(document).ready(function (){`
`>> var $scroll_down_chat = $('#message_board');`

> > SCROLL FUNCTION EXECUTED ON EACH "post_new_message" BROADCAST EVENT 
> >     `>> io.on("post_new_message", function(data){`
> >     `>>> $("#message_board").append("<p>"+ data.new_message +"</p>");`
> >     `>>> $scroll_down_chat.animate({ scrollTop:$scroll_down_chat[0].scrollHeight }, 'fast');`
> >     `>>      });`
> >     `>   }`
> >     `></script>`